# Query and table - MAX and Join

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Still very new to all of this so bear with me.

Have 3 tables

```
table 1: member

Mem_index, Mem_name
1          joe
2          Mark

Table 2: Course

Course_index, Course_Name
1             Math
2             Reading

Table 3 : data

Data index,Member,Course,Score
1           1     1       85
2           1     2       75
3           2     1       95
4           1     2       65
```

SO what I would like to do is create a table:
Do a query and gather all of the courses, find the max score for each course and attribute the member name to it.

Table result should look like:

```
Course, Max score,name
Math    95        Mark
Reading 75        Mark
```

I can do the query individually but unsure of how to loop it and then propogate the data into the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this query for SQL?

```
SELECT c.course_name, MAX( d.score ), m.mem_name 
FROM members m
JOIN data d on m.mem_id = d.member
JOIN course c on c.course_id = d.course
GROUP BY d.course
ORDER BY d.score, m.mem_name, c.course_name
```

Not sure if the field names match up but you get the idea - tested this in sql with some dummy data.

```
Data
Index     Member     Course     Score
1         1          1          60
1         1          1          85

Course
course_id      course_name
1              Math
2              English
3              Science

Members
mem_id        mem_name
1             Mark
2             James
```

You will get the following

```
Course Name    Score     Member
Math           85        Mark
```

Comment: I think that was the nudge I was looking for I will run  with it.

Comment: OK I got close I came up with this: <code>SELECT c.course_name as course, MAX( d.score )as score,d.distance as distance,concat( m.First_Name, ' ',m.Last_name) as name, v.Veh_name as vehicle FROM hc_user m JOIN HC_entries d on m.user_index = d.user JOIN hc_course c on c.course_num = d.course Join hc_vehicle_type v on v.Veh_num = d.vehicle GROUP BY d.course ORDER BY d.score, m.First_name, c.course_name;</code>

Comment: @Sephado Sorry still not sure how to put code into comments. I don't know how to tie the d.distance with the Max(d.score)     right now it is simply pulling the first distance not the distance associated with the Max(d.score) I tried joining to itself but couldn;t make it work

Answer (score 1):

Try this query :

```
SELECT c.course_Name , MAX(d.score),m.mem_name 
FROM data d 
JOIN course c ON d.course=c.course_index 
JOIN members m  ON  m.mem_index = d.member
GROUP BY d.course
ORDER by MAX(d.score) DESC
```